# Does nodejs have a form helper similar to that of ruby's to generate CSRF tokens?

Tags: node.js, csrf, csrf-protection

In ruby one can do something like `<%= form_tag(:action => '/submit') do %> ... <% end %>` to get a form including CSRF tokens.

Is there an existing function in node and how is it implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [caolan-forms plugin](https://github.com/caolan/forms/) for node.js. After that install [express-csrf plugin](https://github.com/hanssonlarsson/express-csrf).

Then you can merge these two, something like:

```
// initializing express
var express = require('express'),

// initializing express-csrf   
csrf = require('express-csrf');

app = express.createServer();

app.dynamicHelpers({
    csrf: csrf.token
});

var forms = require('forms'),
    fields = forms.fields,
    validators = forms.validators;

var reg_form = forms.create({
    username: fields.string({required: true, id: csrf, name: csrf}),
});

// finally render the form
reg_form.toHTML();
```

It would produce:

```
<div class="field required">
   <label for="id_username">Username</label>
   <input type="text" name="[csrf-value]" id="[csrf-value]" value="test" />
</div>
```

**Note:** The caolan-forms' author wrote:

> You'll notice you have to provide your own form tags and submit button, its more flexible this way ;)

## Edit

Since express-csrf is depriciated, instead use [connect bundle](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) and follow [this](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/examples/csrf.js) simple example. Eventually, you would be able to integrate it with *caolan-forms* like:

```
var reg_form = forms.create({
     '_csrf':fields.hidden({value: 'req.session._csrf'}),
      ...
})
```

Comment: Does this automatically require the csrf token on form post? Does it handle ajax automatically or do I need to read the token and add to the values?

Comment: The csfr token will be submitted with or without AJAX form submission. Any cross-site forgery attempt would be sent error with 403 status code in response. Check out the [functionality of `csfr.check()`](https://github.com/hanssonlarsson/express-csrf/blob/master/lib/index.js).

Comment: `This module is deprecated Please use the csrf middleware bundled with Connect instead.` at https://github.com/hanssonlarsson/express-csrf

Comment: I haven't used connect but it sounds promising. Install using `npm install connect` and check its Git repository at https://github.com/senchalabs/connect

Comment: Following example here: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/examples/csrf.js

Comment: Sounds great. The interesting part would be, when you try to integrate it with https://github.com/caolan/forms. Instead of hardcoding the form markup, you would probably need to plant csfr `{token}` token in associative array (`var reg_form = forms.create..` in the above example) then follow the procedure in https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/examples/csrf.js

Comment: Code I ended up using: `app.dynamicHelpers({
  csrf_token: function(req){
    return req.session._csrf;
  },
  form_csrf: function(req){
    return '<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="' + req.session._csrf + '" />';
  }`

Comment: Along with the `app.use(connect.csrf())`

Comment: Indeed its just correct. I was thinking something more arty like `var reg_form = forms.create({ '_csrf':fields.hidden({value: 'req.session._csrf'}), ...})`

Comment: Yeah I suppose that might be more in line with the question asked, so good for reference :). Most of the time I just end up making my own forms though and I would want them to be placed in the view

Comment: Yup, at least caolan-forms plugin is somewhat similar to rails forms helper. The DRY principle is followed while retaining the  modularity and views are pretty much nifty this way. Use CSS to decorate the wrapping div of "field" class if necessary. :)

Comment: I added the Edit section. Hope these findings help the future visitors as well.